# Using conditionals when using python subprocess.call()

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to convert the following bash to python

```
if gfs15_to_am10.py $LAT $LON $ALT $GFS_CYCLE $FORECAST_HOUR \
        > layers.amc 2>layers.err;
```

I am using the subprocess module to try and convert it to python, like so:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'gfs15_to_am10.py',\
        lat, lon,alt, gfs_cycle, forecast_hour])
```

I figure that I can use stdout and stderr to write to layers.amc and layers.err but I don't understand if the "if" statement can be executed using stdout, that would make sense if the bash code intends to execute if and only if some output is generated but I am not a hundred percent sure. I would like to know if there's some error in my thoughts and how do I implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, posting here for the reference of others.

The if statement checks the exit code of the python script, which should be 0, the same should be used for the python code.

Additionally,
the layers.amc and layers.err should be opened prior to the subprocess.call()
and then you can use:

```
subprocess.call(..., stdout=outfile, stderr=errfile)
```